# Angular8 cdk , How to load components inside for loop in Drag and Drop functionality.?

Tags: angular

Drag and Drop in **angular8 cdk** only, i have one doubt. can i load my widgets/card inside for loop ?  i have 40+ widgets need to be displayed in dashboard and all cards are of different sizes and each card drag among each other and drop.
how i call my all 40+ components of different width and height inside cards array given below???
please help me ...

````
<mat-grid-list cols="12" rowHeight="1:1" gutterSize="15px">
          <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of cards; let i = index;" 
                         [colspan]="card.cols" [rowspan]="card.rows">
            <cdk-drop-list [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="drops" [cdkDropListData]="i" >
              <mat-card cdkDrag (cdkDragEntered)="entered($event)" [cdkDragData]="i"
                        class="dashboard-card"  [style.backgroundColor]="card.color">

                <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
/// how to load components here-------------------------------------------->>
                  <h1>{{card.title}}</h1>
                </mat-card-content>
              </mat-card>
            </cdk-drop-list>
          </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>```

```
 cards = [
    { title: 'Card 1', cols: 3, rows: 2},
    { title: 'Card 2', cols: 3, rows: 2 },
    { title: 'Card 3', cols: 3, rows: 2 },
    { title: 'Card 4', cols: 6, rows: 2},
    { title: 'Card 5', cols: 9, rows: 2},
    { title: 'Card 6', cols: 3, rows: 2},
    { title: 'Card 7', cols: 6, rows: 2 },
    { title: 'Card 8', cols: 3, rows: 2 },
   ];
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dragula module for Angular : npm install ng2-dragula

```
<ul dragula="VAMPIRES">
   <li *ngFor="let vamp of vampires">
    {{ vamp.name }} likes {{ vamp.favouriteColor }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

In componet.ts file

```
   constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.dragulaService.createGroup("DRAGULA_EVENTS", {
        direction: 'horizontal',
        moves: (el, source, handle) => handle.className === "group-handle"
    });
    // You can also get all events, not limited to a particular group
    this.subs.add(this.dragulaService.drop()
        .subscribe(({name, el, target, source, sibling}) => {
            console.log(name, el, target, sibling)
        })
    );
}
```

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/

DEMO: [you can see demo click here](https://valor-software.com/ng2-dragula/index.html)

Comment: sorry, i haven't mention, i used angular cdk .